# XSLT renaming element with attribute value?

Tags: xslt

I have this XML:

```
<PARTY>
          <PARTY_ID type="buyer_specific">XXXXXX</PARTY_ID>
          <PARTY_ID type="gln">YYYYYYYYYYYY</PARTY_ID>
          <PARTY_ROLE>buyer</PARTY_ROLE>
</PARTY>
```

And I need the elements PARTY_ID to be named different, preferably set to the same as type

So preferred result would be:

```
<PARTY>
          <buyer_specific>XXXXXX</buyer_specific>
          <gln>YYYYYYYYYYYY</gln>
          <PARTY_ROLE>buyer</PARTY_ROLE>
</PARTY>
```

I know this is probably a easy fix, but I am really new at XSLT..... thx for your patience and help!

Comment: @JesperBloch-Hansen If you spent two days trying to solve this, then you would have been better off spending two days reading books and tutorials: that's a much more productive way of learning the language than trying "a ton of different things" to solve a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get something that is ok for the task at hand working:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="PARTY_ID[@type]">
      <xsl:element name="{@type}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">    
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/2.1">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not ideal, but it works...
Thank you for reading!

Comment: Was about to suggest you that. It is not a trick, this is pure xsl.

Comment: Except that this does not produce the stated expected result: all elements are placed in a namespace, except the renamed `PARTY_ID` elements which are in no-namespace. I doubt that is the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="PARTY_ID[@type]">
     <xsl:element name="{@type}"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<PARTY>
    <PARTY_ID type="buyer_specific">XXXXXX</PARTY_ID>
    <PARTY_ID type="gln">YYYYYYYYYYYY</PARTY_ID>
    <PARTY_ROLE>buyer</PARTY_ROLE>
</PARTY>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<PARTY>
   <buyer_specific>XXXXXX</buyer_specific>
   <gln>YYYYYYYYYYYY</gln>
   <PARTY_ROLE>buyer</PARTY_ROLE>
</PARTY>
```

---

**Explanaion**:

1. Using the identity rule to copy every node "as-is"
2. Overriding the ***[identity rule](https://www.delightfulcomputing.com/xslfaq/xsl/sect2/identity.html)*** with a more specific one matching any `PARTY_ID` element that has a `type` attribute
3. Using an **[`<xsl:element>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl:element)** instruction with **[AVL (Attribute Value Template)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#dt-attribute-value-template)** for the name of the element -- to be constructed from the value of the `type` attribute of the current node.